# When is $C(X,Y)$ unique to the topology $(X,\tau)$?

Tags: general-topology

### The Problem

The full question I want to ask is what properties must $(Y,\tau)$ have that would make $C(X,Y)$ unique to $X$'s topology or

> Given $(X_1,\tau_1)$ and $(X_2,\tau_2)$ with $X_1=X_2$, what properties must $(Y,\tau)$ have for $$C(X_1,Y)=C(X_2,Y)$$
> to imply

$$(X_1,\tau_1)=(X_2,\tau_2)$$

---

### Example (Existence)

It is clear that if $\{y\}$ is open for some $y\in Y$ , $\{y'\}$ is closed for some $y'\in Y$, and $y\neq y'$ then we can find a function for an open set $V$(in either $X_1$ or $X_2$) called $$f_V(x)=\begin{cases} y & x\in V \\ y' & x\not\in V\end{cases}$$

where $y'$ is some other point in Y. This function is continuous(in either $X_1$ or $X_2$ depending on our choice of V) and $$f_V^{-1}(y)=V$$

Thus $V$ must be open in both $X_1$ and $X_2$.

---

### FAQ

**Question:** Why did $\{y\}$ have to be open and $\{y'\}$ have to be closed?

**Answer:**
$f_V$ is modeled around a characteristic function. So the goal was to choose a point $y$ and $y'$ such that $$f_V^{-1}(y)=V$$ and $$f_V^{-1}(y')=X-V$$. For $f_V$ to be continuous $\{y\}$ must be open and $\{y'\}$ must be closed.

**Question:** What is $C(X,Y)$?

**Answer:** The set of all continuous function from $X$ to $Y$.

**Question:** How could we conclude that $V$ is open in both sets?

**Answer:** The assumption is that $$C(X_1,Y)=C(X_2,Y)$$ so if $f_V$
is continuous in $X_1$ it is also continuous in $X_2$ (and vice versa). This means that if $$f_V^{-1}(y)=V$$ is open in $X_1$ it must be open in $X_2$ (and vice versa).

Comment: Assuming $C(X_1,Y)=C(X_2,Y)$ as topological spaces is pretty strong.  Do you want up to homeo?

Comment: @Randall Are you saying that given $C(X_1,Y)=C(X_2,Y)$ then $X_1\cong X_2$? If that is the case how is that different from saying $(X_1, \tau_1)=(X_2,\tau)$ given that they are the same set. If that is what you are saying then yes I do want it up to homeo.

Comment: @bof You are right I meant to state that.

Comment: Why do you say $f_V$ is continuous? Suppose $Y=\mathbb\{0,1\}$ with the discrete topology, $y=0$, $y'=1$, and $x=\mathbb R$ with the usual topology, and let $V$ be an open subset of $\mathbb R$, $V\ne\emptyset$, $V\ne\mathbb R$. Then $f_V$ is a surjection from the connected space $X$ to the disconnected space $Y$, so it can't be continuous.

Comment: @user160110  No, I'm not saying that.  Also, it is possible for $X_1$ to be homeo to $X_2$ with the topologies not being equal.

Comment: If $Y$ is any discrete space with more than one point, then there are points $y,y'\in Y$ such that $\{y\}$ and $\{y'\}$ are open and closed, and 
$y\ne y'$. If $\tau$ is **any** connected topology on a set $X$, then the only continuous functions from $(X,\tau)$ to $Y$ are the constant functions.

Comment: Of course the set $\mathbb R$ has many connected topologies which are distinct and non-homeomorphic.

Comment: Correcting your example: the space $Y$ has the property you want if you can find points $y,y'\in Y$ such that $y\ne y'$ and $\{y\}$ is open **and dense** in $Y$. For example, $Y$ could be the [Sierpiński space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_space).